# Excel create blank cells and replace duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the FILTER function to auto-fill my data.
It's possible to auto create blanks cells, and replace duplicate?
I've been googling for hours and can't figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Here is my example:

```
A  1  SF
A  2  HK
B  3  SF
B  4  NYC
B  5  SF
```

Using the FILTER function to return data only contain "SF"
`=FILTER(A1:B5&"",C1:C5="SF")`

```
A  1
B  3
B  5
```

The result I want:
create a blank cell between A and B
use " to replace the duplicate B

```
A  1

B  3
"  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(data,A1:C5,uniqueLetters,UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,1)),
result,REDUCE("",uniqueLetters,LAMBDA(r,letter,VSTACK(r,"",FILTER(TAKE(data,,2),(INDEX(data,,3)="SF")*(INDEX(data,,1)=letter))))),
result1, DROP(result,2),
result2, MAP(result1,DROP(result,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(ISTEXT(a),IF(a=b,"""",a),a))),
IFERROR(DROP(result2,-1),""))
```

result1 returns an array with an empty row inserted between the letters.

In the next step result1 is compared to second version of result that starts "one row later" to compare for equal values in the row below - if yes letter is replaced by "

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. My filter function reference to another sheet, and I can't make it incorporate into your formula. Can you see if this can put into the formula you wrote? =FILTER(Orders!A2:E325&"",Orders!F2:F325="SF")

Comment: You only need to replace `A1:C5` with your range. And adjust the column IDs within the (data,,x) from FILTER

Comment: Very nice answer. Note that column B need to be actual numbers or it'll show blanks in the second column.

Comment: @P.b that's right - otherwise one have to implement another check logic

Comment: Thank you so much so helping. The data I'm working with also includes Japanese, so it further complicated things.